# Changing vim's status line's "file modified" flag to be more noticeable

Tags: vim, statusline

I do this all the time:

Edit a file, go back to the terminal and execute the script I'm writing… only to realize that I haven't written it to disk yet.

How do I make it so that vim is basically shouting at my eyes whenever the file is unwritten? That tiny [+] isn't good enough. Ideally, I'd like to either increase the number of red plusses being shown, or something more drastic.

FOR INSTANCE, I'm using powerline (purely in an attempt to get a more noticeable 'file has been modified' notifier). I think it'd be pretty great if the main colour at the bottom of the bar changed whenever the file has not been saved.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set vim to display the file modified flag 5 times if you want.

```
set statusline+=%m
```

This adds it one time. Increase the number of "%m" to whatever number you want. Further explanations and tricks here: http://got-ravings.blogspot.co.at/2008/08/vim-pr0n-making-statuslines-that-own.html

Comment: Deep inside that blog post they show you how to set custom highlights on custom regions.

Answer (score 4):

I have written the [StatusLineHighlight plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3383) for that. It changes the color of the statusline to red (customizable) for modified buffers.

It won't work together with Powerline or other fancy statusline modifications, though.

Answer (score 2):

It is not the answer to the question you asked, but why don’t you just do

```
set autowrite
```

to make the problem you mentioned (“go back to the terminal and execute the script I'm writing… only to realize that I haven't written it to disk yet”) go away: this option makes vim save changes you did when you suspend it (note: not when you use `:shell` to spawn a new shell).

For powerline the only thing you can do easily is to edit colorscheme to make more noticeable highlighting: copy `autoload/Powerline/Colorschemes/default.vim` to `~/.vim/autoload/Powerline/Colorschemes/my.vim`, find `Pl#Hi#Segments(['fileinfo.flags'` and in each line add the second color (background one): transform `['brightestred', ['bold']]` to `['white', 'brightestred', ['bold']]` and so on. Then add

```
let g:Powerline_colorscheme='my'
```

to the vimrc and run `:PowerlineClearCache`.

Comment: Ah, but I like everything to be explicit, so autowrite is out. I tried your suggestions - the most comprehensive and on point - but it didn't make a huge difference. It's very annoying how there doesn't seem to be a straightforward way to modify the segment - or rather, that I can't seem to figure out how Powerline works. Thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: @phillmv This segment is defined in `autoload/Powerline/Segments.vim`, you can increase the number of `%M` there. But you then need to use git and have it care about your changes, it is not a thing you can copy to `~/.vim` and expect Powerline to work after next update (unless you copy the default theme as well). It also may conflict with a maximum number of statusline items (up to 80, but powerline uses a lot of them. AFAIR I heard that default theme does use all 80 items if all required plugins are installed, not sure whether it is true: on my system there are only 29 of them).

Comment: With the modified colorscheme, adding a bunch of spaces in that segment kind of did the job, so I switched back to powerline. THIS IS SORT OF WHAT I WANTED, thanks! It kind of messes up with my other segments if the window is at a reduced size, but I don't really need to know the filetype and encoding at all times. Powerline is all kinds of vimscript voodoo; I can't even figure out how to reorder the segments.